# Removing mouse listener (Java) - consume not working

Tags: java, mouselistener

**SOLVED!** Or at least a workaround. Guess I had to crawl to the dark corners of google search, after page five.
ans1.removeMouseListener(ans1.getMouseListeners()[2]); <- removing from the array of Mouse listeners. [0] is the basic listener for JButton. [1] kept for an effect. [2] causing the problem.

I decided to make a short CYOA in java. The answers are in jbuttons. Basically same buttons, different texts. I added a skillcheck to the game, class returning success as a boolean. The problem is, the consume() is not removing the action registered to the mouse click - it is getting more and more instances of skillcheck and "rolls." The related part:

```
public class b03 implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        characters.SkillcheckParty skillcheck = new characters.SkillcheckParty();
        boolean success = skillcheck.scpPerception(12, -5, 40); 
        arg0.consume();
        Battleground.conv.ans1.addMouseListener(new b04());
    }
}
```

**SOLVED!** Or at least a workaround. Guess I had to crawl to the dark corners of google search, after page five.
ans1.removeMouseListener(ans1.getMouseListeners()[2]); <- removing from the array of Mouse listeners. [0] is the basic listener for JButton. [1] kept for an effect. [2] causing the problem.

Comment: please post your solution as a answer if this is solved. Editing you question with "Solved!" is frowned upon. see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for more info

Comment: will do. sorry, as you can see, new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least got a workaround. Guess I had to crawl to the dark corners of google search, after page five.

```
ans1.removeMouseListener(ans1.getMouseListeners()[2]);
```

<- removing from the array of Mouse listeners. [0] is the basic listener for JButton. [1] kept for an effect. [2] causing the problem. Removing all listener:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ans1.getMouseListeners().length-1; i++) {
        ans1.removeMouseListener(ans1.getMouseListeners()[i]);
    }
```

I am open to any comment, addition.